# Tensorflow: How to fix ResourceExhaustedError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, gpu, training-data

I'm trying to recreate these: [Hugging Face: Question Answering Task](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/tasks/question_answering) and [Hugging Face: Question Answering NLP Course](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/7?fw=tf).

I was having this ResourceExhaustedError at the **model.fit()** part.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(x=tf_train_set, batch_size=16, validation_data=tf_validation_set, epochs=3, callbacks=[callback])
```

```
ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'tf_distil_bert_for_question_answering/distilbert/transformer/layer_._4/attention/dropout_14/dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform' defined at (most recent call last):
```

**A bunch of files listed here**

```
Node: 'tf_distil_bert_for_question_answering/distilbert/transformer/layer_._4/attention/dropout_14/dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,12,384,384] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node tf_distil_bert_for_question_answering/distilbert/transformer/layer_._4/attention/dropout_14/dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_9297]
```

I already tried lowering the batch_size.
`model.fit(x=tf_train_set, batch_size=16, validation_data=tf_validation_set, epochs=3, callbacks=[callback])`

I also tried limiting GPU's memory growth
[Limiting GPU memory growth](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)

Here are colab notebooks: [Colab: Question Answering Task](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10QnYEZbBmjgxkmGyiwYB18aoFRPUpgho?usp=sharing) and [Colab: Question Answering NLP Course](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SFisP47O7ZQc_P_Hxcr2i6r_F4_AA2OE?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines at the beginning

```
import os
os.environ["TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR"]="cuda_malloc_async"
```

*Note: Limiting GPU's memory growth, and setting the batch_size wouldn't be necessary.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It means GPU's memory can't afford your batch size or input data size.
So, try to reduce batch size or input data size

Comment: I reduced the batch_size to 16, 4, and even to 1. The error still occurs.